# How to detect whether a web element is invisible?

Tags: javascript, css, xpath

I am trying to find out whether this element `<ul class = 'pagination-buttons no-bullets'>` is visible:

[image]

When `<ul class = 'pagination-buttons no-bullets'>` is visible, its parent element has `class = 'page-number-section'`, when `<ul class = 'pagination-buttons no-bullets'>` is invisible, its parent element has `class = 'page-number-section cloaked'`. The element itself's attributes do not change with its visibility.

I could look at its parent class and verify whether it is visible but is there another way to do it? e.g. something like `pageObj.QuerySelector().visible()`?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to `visibility: hidden` or something else?

Comment: @Dekel, yeah, something like visibility: hidden, but I can not see it as an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `getComputedStyle` you can check the actual value of a css attribute.

Here is an example:

```js
console.log('#a1 visibility is:', window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('a1'), null).getPropertyValue("visibility"));

console.log('#a2 visibility is:',window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('a2'), null).getPropertyValue("visibility"));
```

```css
.hide-inner .some-class {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide-inner">
  <div id="a1" class="some-class">abc</div>
</div>

<div class="show-inner">
  <div id="a2" class="some-class">def</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much, this is exactly what I am looking for.